# Create Fixed Length File in SQL Server From SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create a fixed length file from below input table.Each field has fix length for Example: Employeeid will take 9 (`Employeeid + space(9-len(Employeeid )))` Bytes

Please suggest approach only.Thanks

```
FileType Field    Table_Field   Start_Pos   End_Pos
    A1  CompanyID   Company_id    1         3
    A1  EmployeeID  EID           4         12
    A1  PLAN        PLAN_ID       13        14
    A1  space       space(9)      21        29
    A1  TCode       A1            30        31
    A1  Ad1         ADD1          32        61
    A1  Ad2         ADD2          62        91
    A1  IND         space(1)      92        92
    A1  Fil         space(8 )     93       100
```

Comment: Approach - use `SSIS`, ETL tools are best suited for this kind of activities.

Comment: use BCP or SSIS and all output columns casted to char

Comment: @Abhishek   Thanks All..I am not using any ETL tool, working on SQL Server only

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
select (left(convert(char(100), Company_id), 3 - 1 + 1) +
        left(convert(char(100), EID), 12 - 4 + 1) +
        left(convert(char(100), Plan_id), 14 - 13 + 1) +
        . . . 
       )
from t;
```

This will convert the rows to a fixed length string, with the positions that you want.

Comment: Thanks but company_id,Eid  all values are under field column. We can't select directly..